# Video Ads of Vungle SDK

Tags: win-universal-app

I had follow the instruction from the channel 9 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/How-To-Integrate-the-Vungle-SDK-for-Windows-10?ocid=player
and I get the error below:

General metadata correctness
**Error Found**: The general metadata correctness test detected the following errors:
The assembly VungleSDK in file VungleSDK.winmd has a non-empty manifest resources table. Every Windows Runtime assembly must have an empty manifest resources table.

**Impact if not fixed**: Windows store doesn't allow apps that don't pass Windows Runtime Metadata Validation.

**How to fix**: Please ensure that the compiler you are using to generate your Windows Runtime types is up to date with the Windows Runtime specifications.

I does not understand this errors, anyone can help?

Comment: This is a mistake in the SDK on our end. We had assets loaded in the manifest resources table (where they should not be) and we're planning a release to rectify the issue tomorrow (Wednesday).

Please download the new SDK when it is available and let us know if you still see this error.

Comment: Also, where did you see the "How to fix" you have listed here? This is not correct and will not have any impact on the error.

Comment: Now I use the latest version 1.0.18 its cant install in Visual Studio Community Version

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I had an error look like the same as the problem with the sdk, but not with the SDK, its in my own project.

The project doesen't contains anything except the project.json and refers a SharedProject which contains only one .cs file.

I get the same error, but I can't find the sollution.

I tryed:
 - Add app.manifest (from template)
 - Resource Dictionary
 - Resource File

Both was empty as the error sais "Windows Runtime assembly must have an empty manifest resources table", so I created some empty one.

I would be happy to know what did you do with the Vungle SDK, what caused the problem and what solved it.

The Vungle winmd file contains same files like my projects winmd...

---

Here is the answer for my own problem.

Finally I found what caused the problem, by inspecting the .text file in winmd file and locate the file whose content was included in the .text.

Under the winmd project Properties the template generates a *.rd.xml (* usually your package name) which is a resource dictionary what sould be removed in my case.

I know it won't help to solve the prolem with the old SDK which were patched earlyer, but if somebody get the error message on package validation and don't know what to do, here is something he can try.

(Just to be clear my problem not connected to the SDK I just get the same error message on validation)

Comment: Why do you say it's the same SDK error, but not with the SDK?  Also, since you're posting this as an answer, please just focus on the answer, and not the error and other things you tried.

Comment: You may contact their Support. They help me solve the problems from their support.

Comment: @Teepeemm
1st I wrote here to ask the support in a public way because if the VS template is wrong the problem is common, and no sollution writen on the internet.

It was only luck that in a few minutes I finnaly found the sollution, but when I wrote the question I didn't know the actual sollution.

I could open a new topic with the same error instead of post it under the problem with a 3 party "sdk", but as the error was exacly the same and the reason was may same too I thougth it is better to write here than into a new topic and get "Duplicated".

The goal is find the sollution, and its done.

Comment: I hadn't looked at the edit history.  If you hadn't made your edit, your answer would have probably been deleted for not being an actual answer to the question.  But since you do have an answer to the question, it would be better to just phrase it as "here's the answer".  Including all of the "I had the same problem, and these things didn't solve it" paragraphs just muddies the water and makes it harder to understand your answer.